# Regexp one symbol exactly once through the whole string

Tags: regex

Already have a working regexp ^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]{1,11}$ but recently got an update in validation:
there should be all old validations and new one symbol _ which should appear in whole string exactly once.

Strings must only match:

```
_name
name_
name_name
```

validation should fail for:

```
_name_
__name
etc.
```

tried a few approaches
^[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]{1,11}$
all characters may be _

^(*?)[a-zA-Z0-9 ]{1,11}(*?)$
validates

```
alpha_
_alpha
_alpha_ (shouldn't be valid)
```

but not this one:

```
 alpha_name
```

Comment: Try `^(?=.{1,11}$)[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*_[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$`. If `_` can't appear at the start/end and  is optional, ``^(?=.{1,11}$)[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+(?:_[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+)?$``

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you for reply. Suggested solution worked for mentioned cases but failed for one of the old ones :
"Alpha Name1" should be valid

Comment: [Works for me](https://regex101.com/r/IiGjIT/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes, but it doesn't validate this two cases
```_name

name_```

Comment: What do you mean? They [do not match](https://regex101.com/r/IiGjIT/2).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew
sorry, a bit more info. There are a bunch of old cases that shuld be supported, they include a string consisting of min of 1 and max of 11 characters which might be digits or letter or whitespaces.
Old regex ^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]{1,11}$ totally works for old cases. New cases include underscore sigh plus to old cases. "Alpha Name1" - old case, it might as well be "Alpha Name1_" or "Alpha_Name1" or "_Alpha Name1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```js
^(?=.{1,11}$)[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*(?:_[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ckWQvN/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.{1,11}$)` - a positive lookahead that requires one to eleven chars other than line break chars till end of string
- `[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*` - zero or more letters, digits or spaces
- `(?:_[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*)?` - an optional occurrence of `_` and zero or more letters, digits or spaces
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
^(?=.{1,11}$)([a-zA-Z0-9 ]*)_?(?1)$
```

https://regex101.com/r/lCV5VT/1

Comment: Yeah... I failed to update the link... :)
The correct version is with the `*`